# C# & CF: Design Time Attributes

Tags: c#, coldfusion

I'm using compact framework 3.5 and pocket pc 2003 platform.

I'm writing a custom control for my application. Some properties I want to be exposed as design-time attributes.

The way it is described in MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx) is not actually working.

I get:

> The type or namespace name 'CategoryAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I've used Intellisense to see what attributes I can write. It lists some strange things like:

- EditorBrowsable
- DesignerCategory
- DefaultValue
- DesignTimeVisible

There is more. If I try to use those this way:

```
public partial class Counter : UserControl
{
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[DesignerCategory("Data")]
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
[DefaultValue(0)]
public UInt64 theNumber;
```

..i get following errors:

> Attribute 'DesignerCategory' is not
>   valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'class' declarations.
>
> Attribute 'DesignTimeVisible' is not
>   valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'class, interface'
>   declarations.

What is the correct way to use design time attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you aren't using properties; you should have:

```
public ulong TheNumber { get; set; }
```

or

```
private ulong theNumber;
public ulong TheNumber {
    get { return theNumber; }
    set { theNumber = value; }
}
```

Re the attributes: Essentially, those attributes simply aren't supported (don't exist) for compact-framework. The MSDN article you cite is for "full" .NET. If you look at (for example) [DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) it makes no claim to work on CF.

Properties etc should already be ***available*** to set at design-time; you just don't have the same level of ability to tweak the design-time experience.

As an aside, `ulong` is pretty uncommon in most code, but it isn't a problem.